# Java sockets: Client get IP-adress and port to connect to server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, port

I'm stuck at a homework assignment for my university course.
We are supposed to write a game of Rock-Paper-Scissors using Client and Server, choosing TCP or UDP.
The assignment for the client part is:
"Get the IP-address and port of the server at the beginning and than use this information to connect to the server."
And server:
"The port needs to be set to a number between 10000 and 20000 at the start using command line input."
Now this got me wondering. How is the Client supposed to get the Ip-Adress and port of the server if it is not connected to the server yet?
And normally the client and the server creates a socket and the  **server** listens if a client wants to connect and then accepts the request, making a connection, not the client, like it is requested in the assignment. Isn't it impossible to know the server, if not connected yet?

I got a version working, if the server goes:

```
// Setting the port via console, making an output: "please enter valid port" and returns the entered port number
    ServerTest.port = ServerTest.getPort();
...
ServerSocket testSocket = new ServerSocket(ServerTest.port);
```

and the client:

```
private static String host = "localhost";
private static Integer port = 1337;
...
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ClientTest.host, ClientTest.port);
```

if I set the port to 1337 when starting the server.

Then I tried something like

```
//Client
port = ServerTest.getServerPort();
...
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ClientTest.host, ClientTest.port);
```

and in the server-class:

```
public static Integer getServerPort(){
    return port;
}
```

But that throws an "Connection refused"-exception, even if I first the server at first, set the port and than start the client.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: "How is the Client supposed to get the Ip-Adress and port of the server if it is not connected to the server yet?" Well it can't. How do you visit a friend if you don't know his address? You don't.

Comment: You have to use the same port as the server does. Just use a fix port in both programs. I don't think you shall get the port of the server programmatically - for that purpose, you have to scan all ip-adresses in your network and the correspondig ports that are listening - this seems a bit much for a homework

Comment: @Kayaman yes, exactly what I think, it's impossible.

Comment: @Supahupe with a fixed port it's working, but it's not exactly what I need to do. With starting the server, you need to assign a port (I need to present that code, so the tutor will enter a random number and the code has to work with it) and then the client needs to connect to that port, which is why I tried the getServerPort() method, but it isn't working...

Comment: Does the client know the server's ip address?

Comment: @supahupe No, not explicitly. I run client and server on my pc, so they have the same ip address. Can the client even know the server's IP address before they are connected?

Comment: If you want to implement a "bigger" client-/server-application, your client needs to know the servers ip-address at less. In general, it is also a convention to define a fix port where the server is listening on client connections which the clients also know. For your homework, you could make a loop from 0 to 65535 (this is the highest possible tcp/udp port) and let your client try to connect to each port. If your server accepts the connection, he can send a "Hello-Message" to your client so you know that your are connected to the right port. I do not know another solution for this problem

Comment: @Supahupe okay, thank you for your help I will try to implement that.